# 'x' and 'y' lengths differ with fft in R

Tags: r, fft

Hi I took the example from: [stat.ethz.ch](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2005-August/078197.html)

```
## Now let's look at some artificial data:
x <- seq(100000)/1000  # pretend we're sampling at 1 kHz

## We'll put in two frequency components, plus a dc offset
f1 <- 5  # Hz
f2 <- 2  # Hz
y <- 0.1*sin(2*pi*f1*x) + sin(2*pi*f2*x) + 50
fft.y <- fft(y)
delta <- x[2] - x[1]
f.Nyquist <- 1 / 2 / delta
f <- f.Nyquist*c(seq(length(x)/2), -rev(seq(length(x)/2)))/(length(x)/2)

par(mfrow=c(2,2))
plot(x,y, type='l', xlim=c(0,20))
plot(f, Mod(fft.y), type='l', log='y')

## Now let's zoom in and mark the points were I expect to see peaks:
plot(f, Mod(fft.y), type='l', log='y', xlim=c(-10,10))
```

Right now I do have a dataframe to analyse - df. First column (V1) of df is date, second is value (V2). I set the points but I am always getting one more fft value as in f (what is doing Nyquist). So getting:  "'x' and 'y' lengths differ". Don't know where the problem is!

```
y <- df$V2
fft.y <- fft(y)
delta <- 10 # I know that there are 10sec between values
f.Nyquist <- 1 / 2 / delta
f <- f.Nyquist*c(seq(length(df$V1)/2), -rev(seq(length(df$V1)/2)))/(length(df$V1)/2)
```

df looks like:

```
07032012-185821;20.0
07032012-185831;12.0
07032012-185841;14.0
```

and there are around 20000 obersvations

Thanks for help!

Comment: is it possible to share `df`?

Comment: maybe it is kind of limiting problem- do have around 20000 observations - sorry about df, i will give an exaple how it looks like.

Comment: It is even better to generate some random numbers that mimic your situation, e.g. using `runif`.

Comment: Don't getting what you mean: Date format doesn't matter - I only take the length. Second colum are only values.

Comment: we are asking for reproducible example. your current example doesn't produce error.

Comment: can you post `dim(df)`?

Comment: First: check to see if `length(fft.y)` is in fact greater than `length(df$V1)` (or `length(df$V2)` as well).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking a wild guess, I think the problem occurs when length of the observations is odd. Basically,

```
length(c(seq(length(df$V1)/2), -rev(seq(length(df$V1)/2))))
```

is not equal to

```
length(df$V2)
```

This is due to rounding of integers ex: `seq(length(1:9)/2)` is same as `seq(length(1:8)/2)` though the lengths of original vectors differ.

**Edit:**
It can be fixed by:

```
if (length(df$V2) %% 2 == 1)
{
  f <- f.Nyquist*c(seq(length(df$V1)/2), 0, -rev(seq(length(df$V1)/2)))/(length(df$V1)/2)
} else
{
  f <- f.Nyquist*c(seq(length(df$V1)/2), -rev(seq(length(df$V1)/2)))/(length(df$V1)/2)
}
```

Comment: Yes number of observations is odd! I corrected - its running! Is there any other solution not having the problem if the number of observations is odd?

Comment: for now, you can can just drop the last observation if its odd. one less out of ~20000 should be ok.

Comment: Anyone who makes *correct* wild guesses like that deserve an SO gold medal!

Comment: Well, spending nearly 80 hours per week on SO does have some effect ;)